# update ipad2 3G jailbreaked to ios 7 and it got stuck on error 14

Tags: itunes, ipad, jailbreak, ios

I tried to update my ipad 2 3G jailbreaked to ios 7 and it got stuck on error 14 and it has been in "recovery mode" itunes screen ever since.

I have put the ipad on DFU mode 100x then try to restore it.
I have changed different ports and usb cables.
I have used many different OSs(Mac & Win).
I have tried using tinyumbrella and RecBoot to try to kick it out of recovery.
I tried changing, modifying the hosts files.
I have restarted the computer numerous times.
and I used latest versions of itunes.

and my log file is uploaded [here](http://www.mediafire.com/view/x67qibwhcpm2b6y/iPadUpdater.log)

any idea?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just connect your iPad to your PC and click on "Restore to factory". iTunes will download the latest version of iOS supported and install it, which in this case will install iOS 7 on your iPad.